# Find most recent value given a condition in a pandas dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I'm looking to generate a new column which returns the most recent value which was not value 'C'

For example I would like to be able to generate 'New_Column' as below

```
 Current_Column    New_Column
      B               B
      S               S
      B               B
      S               S
      C               S
      B               B
      S               S
      C               S
      C               S
      B               B
```

I've tried using the .shift() method which works fine until you get to 2 or more consecutive 'C' values.

I have been able to achieve the column by using a for loop which .loc inside, but this is simply too slow on a large scale.

Thanks for any help.

Answer (score 2):

try via `where()` and `ffill()`:

```
df['New_Column']=df['Current_Column'].where(df['Current_Column']!='C').ffill()
```

**OR**

via `np.where()` and `ffill()`:

```
#import numpy as np  
df['New_Column']=np.where(df['Current_Column']!='C',df['Current_Column'],np.nan).ffill()
```

**OR**

via `mask()` and `ffill()`:

```
#thanks to @HenryEcker for this
df['New_Column']=df['Current_Column'].mask(df['Current_Column'].eq('C')).ffill()
```

Comment: @Michael If it solved your query then you can try considering accepting the answer so to indicate others that the issue is solved.... thnx ***:)***